# How to add new array objects with int value

Tags: arrays, swift

I have dynamic array in my project:

```
var firstArray = [FirstArray]()
```

Also I have another array in my view:

```
var TypeId = [""]
```

I want to add `1` objects into `TypeId` array size of `firstArray.count`.

For example: firstArray.count = 7, TypeId Array output must be = ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]

Also how to get TypeId array values to string inside like
`1,1,1,1,1,1,1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `typeID` array contains the number of element equal to `firstArray` you can use `map` like this.

```
var typeID = firstArray.map { _ in String("1") }
```

**Edit :** Join `typeID` array elements by `,`

```
let typeIDString = typeID.joinWithSeparator(",")
```

Comment: mate also how can i get thats with string output like 1,1,2,1 ? can you add this code inside your answer  ?

Comment: In which basis should i add `2` instead of `1`?

Comment: yeah must be output 1,1,1,1,1,1,1  I will send them remote get

Answer (score 1):

your typeID array is an array of strings, change it to

```
var typeID : [Int] = []
typeID.append(firstArray.count)
```

or if u want it to be an array of strings

when u add an integer to it, make sure you convert it to Strings

```
typeID.append(String(firstArray.count))
```

Comment: that codes gives output ["","4","4","4","4"] must be 4 object and inside not 4 must be 1

Comment: Appending a string to an Int array?!

Comment: because when u defined the array u already added your first item in index 0, var TypeId = [""], you created an array that holds strings and you already added on empty string to it, instead, var typeId: [String] = [], this will be an empty array that can append strings only, or var typeID: [Int] = [] , this is an empty array that can append integers